# Pass for vs Pass off as

Tags: word-usage

I was helping a friend out who didn't speak English very well on the phone and I told him I would **pass off as/pass for** him in order to solve his problem with his phone company. I'm not sure if what I said is very natural and usable. So I'm here to ask you guys what should I say when telling someone that I will pretend to be them.

Answer (score 1):

To **pass for** your friend would be to successfully impersonate that person; to try to do this would be to **pass yourself off** as your friend.

[Pass for](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pass%20for)

[Pass off](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pass%20off)